# Instantiating an object in run method has no effect

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

As shown in the code below, when I instantiate an object in the constructor the run method works normally, but if I instantiated the object in the run method I receive no result.

Why that is happening?

**code**:

```
private class TTSReg extends TimerTask {

        TTSCtrl mTTS = null;

        TTSReg() {
            this.mTTS = new TTSCtrl(getApplicationContext());
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {

        //this.mTTS = new TTSCtrl(getApplicationContext());//if this line was activated, the rest would not work
            if ((mVelocity < 1) && (mEngSpeed >= 600)) {

                this.mTTS.pronounce(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.rule_velocity_1));
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the value of `getApplicationContext()` the same when both are executed?

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: getApplicationContext() seems to be the problem maker here..

Comment: @AndyTurner yes it the same